# Menu bootstrap com logo no meio

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Alguem poderia me ajudar de como fazer o menu bootstrap do modelo abaixo?
Não estou conseguindo fazer com 2 ul de menu com a imagem no centro, para ir alinhando no responsivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O próprio menu que você demonstra já foi construído em Bootstrap. Basta olhar, copiar, e editar o código fonte conforme a necessidade. (Link original http://www.hpadvocacia.com.br/)

```
<nav class="nav-desk navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top row affix-top" id="mainNav">
     <div class="superior">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#escrito" class="menu-dez">O Escritório</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php/equipe/">Equipe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php/areas-de-atuacao/">Áreas de Atuação</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
                <a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php">
                    <img style="margin: auto;" src="http://hpsadvogados.com/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-79c7610/library/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php/artigos/">Artigos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php/noticias/">Notícias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://hpsadvogados.com/index.php/contato/">Contato</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img style="margin: auto;" src="http://hpsadvogados.com/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-79c7610/library/images/seta.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>  
    </nav>
```

Observa-se que há duas seções `ul` conforme você necessita.